# How to import a(n) (AWS) badge on Credly?

Tags: aws

**Aim**

Aim is to add digital badges for passing certifications to my LinkedIn profile. AWS itself indicates that one should use Credly to make that work.

**Steps to reproduce**

- pass an exam, e.g. AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner
- login to https://www.certmetrics.com/amazon/
- click on `Digital Badges` tab

> AWS Certification digital badges are provided via Credly’s digital
> badging platform.

- create an account https://www.credly.com
- sign in

> Complete Your Profile

- linkedin profile was added, but the `Complete Your Profile` message still appears. I do not know whether that is required to get the badge in Credly.

**Questions**

- <s>Why does the `Complete Your Profile` message still appear in Credly, while a linkedin account had been associated?</s> After associating LinkedIn and logging out and logging again the message disappeared.
- Why is my AWS badge not shown in Credly?
- How does Credly work?

**Attempts to solve the issue**

- My email account is identical to the one I am using to login to https://www.aws.training/certification
- I checked my spam folder for message from Credly, but nothing was found

**Discussion**

- Perhaps the issue is caused as the Credly account was created after passing the exam.
- Maybe it will take a couple of days when one will receive an email for importing the badge in Credly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to wait for five days when I received an email that contained an Accept button. When I accepted it, the AWS Cloud Practitioner certificate became visible in my credly. If it will take longer than five days you could contact aws support. Also verify whether you do not have more than one AWS account with the same email address. I removed the duplicated email address as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the email you used to sign in to the AWS training portal matches the one you used to register the credly account. Note the AWS training portal account email address may be different than the account tied to your AWS user account.